# Get all link and address information when listenning to a PF_NETLINK socket

Tags: c, netlink

I've written a peace of code that notifies me whenever relevant (to me) networking information changes (mainly listenning to RTM_NEWADDR, RTM_DELADDR, RTM_NEWLINK and RTM_DELLINK.
this works pretty fine, each time I unplug, change ip or whatsoever I get notified.
only problem, is the first time I launch my code, I would like it to give me the whole current status (RTM_GETLINK and RTM_GETADDR).

I am able to request either RTM_GETLINK or RTM_GETADDR:

```
memset(&req, 0, sizeof(req));
req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_len   = NLMSG_LENGTH(sizeof(struct rtgenmsg));
req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_flags = NLM_F_REQUEST | NLM_F_DUMP; /* request to dump all kernel subsystem */
req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_type  = RTM_GETLINK;  /* link information              */
req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_seq   = 1;
req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_pid   = pid;
req.rtgenmsg.rtgen_family = AF_UNSPEC;

iovec.iov_base = &req;
iovec.iov_len  = req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_len;

memset(&msghdr, 0, sizeof(msghdr));
msghdr.msg_iov     = &iovec;
msghdr.msg_iovlen  = 1;
msghdr.msg_name    = &addr;
msghdr.msg_namelen = sizeof(addr);

/*
** TODO: check for number of sent characters
**       on error display errno
*/
sendmsg(nls, &msghdr, 0);

/* do listening stuff... */
```

but if I request both at the same time:

```
req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_type  = RTM_GETLINK | RTM_GETADDR;
```

I only get ip informtion.

am I supposed to use two different sockets, on for the requests and the other one for listening, or is it possible to do all that in the same socket ?

I've tried performing a send for each request, and using seq (increasing it for the second request), I am able to see that the second reply is only 40 bytes long :(

```
memset(&kms.addr, 0, sizeof(kms.addr));
kms.addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;

/* prepare request */
memset(&req, 0, sizeof(req));
req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_len   = NLMSG_LENGTH(sizeof(struct rtgenmsg));
req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_flags = NLM_F_REQUEST | NLM_F_DUMP /*| NLM_F_ACK*/; /* request to dump all kernel subsystem */
req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_type  = RTM_GETLINK;                /* link information                     */
req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_seq   = 1;
req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_pid   = pid;
req.rtgenmsg.rtgen_family = AF_UNSPEC;

iovec.iov_base = &req;
iovec.iov_len  = req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_len;

memset(&msghdr, 0, sizeof(msghdr));
msghdr.msg_iov     = &iovec;
msghdr.msg_iovlen  = 1;
msghdr.msg_name    = &kms.addr;
msghdr.msg_namelen = sizeof(kms.addr);

/*
** TODO: check for number of sent characters
**       on error display errno
*/
sendmsg(kms.nls, &msghdr, 0);

memset(&req, 0, sizeof(req));
req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_len   = NLMSG_LENGTH(sizeof(struct rtgenmsg));
req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_flags = NLM_F_REQUEST | NLM_F_DUMP /*| NLM_F_ACK*/; /* request to dump all kernel subsystem */
req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_type  = RTM_GETADDR;                /* link information                     */
req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_seq   = 2;
req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_pid   = pid;
req.rtgenmsg.rtgen_family = AF_UNSPEC;

iovec.iov_base = &req;
iovec.iov_len  = req.nlmsghdr.nlmsg_len;

memset(&msghdr, 0, sizeof(msghdr));
msghdr.msg_iov     = &iovec;
msghdr.msg_iovlen  = 1;
msghdr.msg_name    = &kms.addr;
msghdr.msg_namelen = sizeof(kms.addr);

/* do listening stuff... */
```

Analyzing it a bit more, it seems I get an NLMSG_ERROR message type.
with error code -16
meaning "device or ressource busy".

if I read the socket after each send, I don't get the problem. but I'd rather be able do all my requests, and only then gather all the replies...

Comment: I'm running into the exact same problem - have you found out if it is possible to send more than one request before reading from the socket?

Comment: Nevermind, according to [here](http://lists.openwall.net/netdev/2007/03/06/214) the kernel will refuse to send messages if there is anything left in the receive buffer and you set NLM_F_DUMP (so no).

Comment: RTM_GETLINK and RTM_GETADDR are not bit masks, so they cannot be or'ed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an answer I found in http://www.carisma.slowglass.com/~tgr/libnl/doc/core.html

> Optionally, the kernel may send out notifications for configuration
>   changes allowing userspace to listen for changes instead of polling
>   frequently. Notifications typically reuse an existing message type and
>   rely on the application using a separate socket to differ between
>   requests and notifications but you may also specify a separate message
>   type.

but not sure what this means:

> but you may also specify a separate message type.

Answer (score 3):

User space needs to wait for NLMSG_DONE netlink control message before sending next request to netlink socket. In other words, if you want to send several netlink requests in a row, then the sequence should look like this:

1. Send req1
2. Wait for NLMSG_DONE
3. Send req2
4. Wait for NLMSG_DONE
5. ...